# What happens when I use angular.module(...).controller(...).directive(...)?And why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I think this equals to

```
var module = angular.module(...);
module.controller(...);
module.directive(...);
```

But I'm not sure. And I don't know what happens in angular and why I could write code this way.

I try to debug and trace it but it's so confused.

Comment: `angular.module` returns a module. Each of `config`, `controller`, `directive`, `factory`, `service`, `provider`, etc on a module instance return that instance so you can chain the calls

Comment: @Phil I just looked the post you mentioned. really helps! So each member function will return "this" and the code could be wrote in a chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens when I use angular.module(…).controller(…).directive(…)?And why?

#### Short answer

This is good way to write your code in one file.

If you want to split Angular project to different files, use 2nd approach:

```
var app = angular.module(...);
app.controller(...);
app.directive(...);
```

---

#### Long answer

Also take a look on this angular code snippets (took from https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.js):

You can see  `controller`, `directive`, `module`, `filter`, `factory`, `value`, `provider`, `decorator`, `animation`, `config`, `component` ,`run`  returns `moduleInstance`

```
function setupModuleLoader(window) {

  var $injectorMinErr = minErr('$injector');
  var ngMinErr = minErr('ng');

  function ensure(obj, name, factory) {
    return obj[name] || (obj[name] = factory());
  }

  var angular = ensure(window, 'angular', Object);

  // We need to expose `angular.$$minErr` to modules such as `ngResource` that reference it during bootstrap
  angular.$$minErr = angular.$$minErr || minErr;

  return ensure(angular, 'module', function() {
    /** @type {Object.<string, angular.Module>} */
    var modules = {};


    return function module(name, requires, configFn) {
      var assertNotHasOwnProperty = function(name, context) {
        if (name === 'hasOwnProperty') {
          throw ngMinErr('badname', 'hasOwnProperty is not a valid {0} name', context);
        }
      };

      assertNotHasOwnProperty(name, 'module');
      if (requires && modules.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        modules[name] = null;
      }
      return ensure(modules, name, function() {
        if (!requires) {
          throw $injectorMinErr('nomod', "Module '{0}' is not available! You either misspelled " +
             "the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you " +
             "specify the dependencies as the second argument.", name);
        }

        /** @type {!Array.<Array.<*>>} */
        var invokeQueue = [];

        /** @type {!Array.<Function>} */
        var configBlocks = [];

        /** @type {!Array.<Function>} */
        var runBlocks = [];

        var config = invokeLater('$injector', 'invoke', 'push', configBlocks);

        /** @type {angular.Module} */
        var moduleInstance = {
          // Private state
          _invokeQueue: invokeQueue,
          _configBlocks: configBlocks,
          _runBlocks: runBlocks,


          requires: requires,

          name: name,

          provider: invokeLaterAndSetModuleName('$provide', 'provider'),


          factory: invokeLaterAndSetModuleName('$provide', 'factory'),

          service: invokeLaterAndSetModuleName('$provide', 'service'),

          value: invokeLater('$provide', 'value'),

          constant: invokeLater('$provide', 'constant', 'unshift'),

          decorator: invokeLaterAndSetModuleName('$provide', 'decorator'),

          animation: invokeLaterAndSetModuleName('$animateProvider', 'register'),

          filter: invokeLaterAndSetModuleName('$filterProvider', 'register'),

          controller: invokeLaterAndSetModuleName('$controllerProvider', 'register'),

          directive: invokeLaterAndSetModuleName('$compileProvider', 'directive'),

          component: invokeLaterAndSetModuleName('$compileProvider', 'component'),

          config: config,

          run: function(block) {
            runBlocks.push(block);
            return this;
          }
        };

        if (configFn) {
          config(configFn);
        }

        return moduleInstance;

        function invokeLater(provider, method, insertMethod, queue) {
          if (!queue) queue = invokeQueue;
          return function() {
            queue[insertMethod || 'push']([provider, method, arguments]);
            return moduleInstance;
          };
        }

        function invokeLaterAndSetModuleName(provider, method) {
          return function(recipeName, factoryFunction) {
            if (factoryFunction && isFunction(factoryFunction)) factoryFunction.$$moduleName = name;
            invokeQueue.push([provider, method, arguments]);
            return moduleInstance;
          };
        }
      });
    };
  });
}
```

> Why is it better?

Both approaches do the same so developer will decide what is better for his project structure

> for efficiency?

There is no efficiency value measurement, both has same efficiency. No performance penalty.

> for what?

In project I want to write each directive each controller each ... in separate file so I use `app.controller(...);`, `app.service(...);` ,...

However *common* directives I want to put in one file so I use:

```
app.directive(…).directive(…).directive(…).directive(…).directive(…)
```

---

Hope it will spread the light on your understanding :)

Comment: Why is it better? for efficiency ? or for what?

Comment: @bo yang one is not better than the other. Chainable methods are a convenience for the developer. If you need to declare a module, controller and directive in one file, use them. If you split your code neatly, don't use them.

Comment: @boyang see my edit

Comment: @MaximShoustin ok, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is called a fluent API.

Each method will return the module instance, so that another method may be called.

To illustrate we can create a class that does something similar.

```
class Module {

  controller() {
    console.log('controller');
    return this;
  }

  directive() {
    console.log('directive');
    return this;
  } 
}
```

When each method has finished, it will return the module instance `this` so that another method can be chained.

So now we can use this class and chain the methods like this:

```
new Module().controller().directive();
```

Or

```
const module = new Module();
module.controller();
module.directive();
```